# unittests fails on build server with Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ClassCleanupBehavior

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, csproj, build-error

I got an assembly that builds and unit tests fine on my PC, but fails to test on the build PC. It has been failing for about a month. I've most likely done something wrong. Here is the response I get from the build server.

```
16:29:38     Project "xyz.Utilities.UnitTests.csproj": VSTest
16:29:40     Test run for C:\Bin\Release\net5.0-windows\xyz.Utilities.UnitTests.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)
16:29:40     Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.11.0
16:29:40     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
16:29:40     
16:29:40     Starting test execution, please wait...
16:29:40     A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
16:29:41     An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ClassCleanupBehavior' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

16:29:41     Stack trace:
16:29:41        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.MSTestExecutor.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 sources, IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
16:29:41        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.RunTestsWithSources.InvokeExecutor(LazyExtension`2 executor, Tuple`2 executorUriExtensionTuple, RunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle)
16:29:41        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Execution.BaseRunTests.RunTestInternalWithExecutors(IEnumerable`1 executorUriExtensionMap, Int64 totalTests)
16:29:41     
16:29:41     
16:29:41     Test Run Failed.
16:29:41     
16:29:41     Build FAILED.
16:29:41         0 Warning(s)
16:29:41         0 Error(s)
```

My project file is quite simple:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
        <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
        <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\Bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
        <CheckForOverflowUnderflow>true</CheckForOverflowUnderflow>
        <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\Bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="EasyTcp" Version="4.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.11.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\xyz.Utilities\xyz.Utilities.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I think it has something to do with the version of Visual Studio on the build server. We are running Teamcity. Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: I've got the same situation for a net48 full framework solution. Please let me know if you have found anything in the meantime. It happens locally as well for me, running dotnet test. Our set-up includes specflow which is calling the ClassCleanupBehavior.

Comment: hmm, I fixed it somehow.. (very helpfull - I know, sorry)
but I ended up forcing all the projects in the solution to run 
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework> 
and did a 
dotnet.restore - in my teamcity build steps..

... and removed a '\' after the $(SolutionDir)Bin\$(Configuration) ...

Comment: Ok thanks for getting back to me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Upgrade your NuGet packages to the latest and it should fix your problem.  I think you need 2.2.8 for `MSTest.TestAdapter` and `MSTest.TestFramework`.

Comment: that could be juet the fix.. hmm I har 2.2.7 in the failing unit test project and 2.2.8 in one that works ...

Comment: I upgraded to use 2.2.8 & microsoft.net.test.sdk 17.0.0
and it fixed the problem

Comment: I had exactly the same error but update to version 2.2.8 didn't solve the issue. It seems it started since I updated to VS 2022. I will try to install latest VS updates.

Comment: We found that for us, lingering references to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework*` in the csproj file caused these NuGet packages to not take effect in VS 2022.

Comment: If You are up to date with the packages mentioned in the answer, this still might be not enough to prevent the issue. In my case in addition I've had to uninstall these two redundant packages:
*Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel* &
*Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform*

Answer (score 9):

I've upgraded as suggested and it works fine now.
[image]

Comment: Could you move this to a comment on the answer